# Need to unlock for the system to suspend when using custom script with xss-lock

Tags: i3, suspend, screen-lock

When I run `systemctl suspend`, my screen locks first, as is expected. However, it remains in locked state and does not suspend. It then suspends after I've unlocked it. I think this started after I've started using a bash script as my locker.

The xss-lock command is:

```
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- ./path/to/locker.sh arguments
```

The locker script contains some image modification stuff and it ends with:

```
i3lock --nofork -e -i /tmp/lock.png
```

Comment: Use absolute paths for all the commands in your "locker script". Your `$PATH` and other environment variables are different.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix the last line of the locker script to be:

```
i3lock --nofork -e -i /tmp/lock.png &
```

That fixed the issue.